# plotting histogram of a column with another column as frequency

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
> df 
     City    Customerid     Count
  Berlin     12546         25
  Boston     21456         29
  London     23163         36
  Berlin     12546         57
  Boston     21462         49
  London     23565         76
  Berlin     12546         45
  Boston     51426         89
  London     23159         76
```

I want to create a plot with city in X axis, sum of count for each city as frequency. The sum of count should appear above each bar of the histogram for the corresponding city.

Comment: you want a `barplot` in R, not the `hist` command

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
p <- barplot(df$Count, names.arg = df$City, ylim = c(0, 100))
text(x = p, y = df$Count, label = df$Count, pos = 3, cex = 0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @user_flow  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.